# How do I split this string into an array?

Tags: php

So I have some data from querying a game server and I need to find a way to extract the information so that it can be used on my site.

```
# 7 "player1" 1156 STEAM_0:4:00100365   0 09:52   84    3 175.77.234.241:27505
# 8 "player2" 1149 STEAM_0:0:39163243  2 14:05   52    0 109.175.131.239:65423
# 9 "player " 1159 STEAM_0:0:162  31 07:19   45    0 78.1.126.130:27025
#10 "gameer123" 1146 STEAM_0:0:701135   4 16:41   94    0 191.200.0.100:14097
```

The lines above are in the format:
"id" "name" "userid" "uniqueid" "frag" "time" "ping" "loss" "adr"

How would I extract this information and turn it into an array so I have something like this

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 0
        [Name] => Player0
        [Frags] => 0
        [Time] => 50856
        [Uniqueid] => STEAM_0:4:001534362
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 0
        [Name] => Player1
        [Frags] => 4
        [Time] => 1447
        [Uniqueid] => STEAM_0:4:00100365
    )
```

BTW I only need the players name, frags, time and uniqueid.

Comment: explode on new lines then spaces.

Comment: in which format the data you receive from server in an array or in other format ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$keys = ["id", "name", "userid", "uniqueid", "frag", "time", "ping", "loss", "adr"];
$result = [];

foreach($array as $row){
    $row_array = preg_split('/\s+\"([^\"]+)\"\s+|#\s*|\s+/', $row, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $result[] = array_combine($keys, $row_array);
    }
    var_export($result);
```

result

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '7',
    'name' => 'player1',
    'userid' => '1156',
    'uniqueid' => 'STEAM_0:4:00100365',
    'frag' => '0',
    'time' => '09:52',
    'ping' => '84',
    'loss' => '3',
    'adr' => '175.77.234.241:27505',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '8',
    'name' => 'player2',
    'userid' => '1149',
    'uniqueid' => 'STEAM_0:0:39163243',
    'frag' => '2',
    'time' => '14:05',
    'ping' => '52',
    'loss' => '0',
    'adr' => '109.175.131.239:65423',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '9',
    'name' => 'player ',
    'userid' => '1159',
    'uniqueid' => 'STEAM_0:0:162',
    'frag' => '31',
    'time' => '07:19',
    'ping' => '45',
    'loss' => '0',
    'adr' => '78.1.126.130:27025',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '10',
    'name' => 'gameer123',
    'userid' => '1146',
    'uniqueid' => 'STEAM_0:0:701135',
    'frag' => '4',
    'time' => '16:41',
    'ping' => '94',
    'loss' => '0',
    'adr' => '191.200.0.100:14097',
  ),
)
```

Comment: That's a tidy solution.
You may want to adjust your split regex so that you don't chop that space off of "player " in the 3rd row as it appears to be part of the string.

Comment: `$mysql_result_rows` comes from where? Not seeing it in OP's post. Suppose it stands for the original string split by newlines?

Comment: @jpheldson you are exactly right about spaces. I've updated the answer to take it

Answer (score 2):

Here's another RegEx approach, using named patterns that are directly recycled into array keys for your clean, final array. You can use any of the RegEx pattern sets suggested here with the solution below, simply add `(?<Keyname>...)` at the start of each the patterns' brackets to make them named.

```
$data = <<<EOL
# 7 "player1" 1156 STEAM_0:4:00100365   0 09:52   84    3 175.77.234.241:27505
# 8 "player2" 1149 STEAM_0:0:39163243  2 14:05   52    0 109.175.131.239:65423
# 9 "player" 1159 STEAM_0:0:162  31 07:19   45    0 78.1.126.130:27025
#10 "gameer123" 1146 STEAM_0:0:701135   4 16:41   94    0 191.200.0.100:14097
EOL;

/* Matching the source data with named patterns */

preg_match_all('#(?<Id>\d+)\s+"(?<Name>[[:alnum:]]+)"\s+\d+\s+(?<Uniqueid>STEAM_[0-9_:]+)\s+(?<Frags>\d+)\s+(?<Time>[\d:]{5})#m', $data, $fields, PREG_SET_ORDER);

/* Cleaning up the numeric keys from RegEx matches */

foreach($fields as $num=>$set) {
    $fields[$num] = array_diff_key($set, array_flip( array_filter( array_keys($set), 'is_int')) );
}

print_r($fields);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 7
            [Name] => player1
            [Uniqueid] => STEAM_0:4:00100365
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 09:52
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 8
            [Name] => player2
            [Uniqueid] => STEAM_0:0:39163243
            [Frags] => 2
            [Time] => 14:05
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 9
            [Name] => player
            [Uniqueid] => STEAM_0:0:162
            [Frags] => 31
            [Time] => 07:19
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 10
            [Name] => gameer123
            [Uniqueid] => STEAM_0:0:701135
            [Frags] => 4
            [Time] => 16:41
        )

)
```

Note that I've trimmed the third line of your source data from `"player "` into `"player"`, presume that was a typo. If player names have other characters, add them in: `(?<Name>[[:alnum:] _-]+)` etc.

========

I recycled the named-pattern int-key-cleaner into a function, in case someone needs to use often.

```
    /* In place of the foreach-loop above, use: */

$fields = remove_int_keys_pma($fields);

    /* And stick these two functions somewhere. */

/* Remove integer keys from preg_match_all sets. (Must use PREG_SET_ORDER.) */

function remove_int_keys_pma($array) {
    foreach($array as $k=>$set) {
        $array[$k] = remove_int_keys($set);
    }
    return $array;
}

/* Remove integer keys from an array. */

function remove_int_keys($array) {
    return array_diff_key($array, array_flip( array_filter( array_keys($array), 'is_int')) );
}
```

Comment: ...and if someone has a simpler way of removing numeric keys from an array, please let me know. Unfortunately there is no `array_filter_keys()` natively in PHP, so I have to flip keys and values etc. Would love to use less than four functions in a chain for the cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function explode();

```
$result = [];
$number = 0;
foreach($mysql_result_rows as $row){
    $row_array = explode(' ', $row);
    $result[$number]['Id'] = trim($row_array['0'], ' ');
    $result[$number]['Name'] = trim($row_array['1'], '"');
    $result[$number]['Frags'] = trim($row_array['4'], ' ');
    $result[$number]['Time'] = trim($row_array['5'], ' ');
    $result[$number]['Uniqueid'] = trim($row_array['3'], ' ');
    $number++; 
}
```

Comment: Result of your code `Array ( [0] => Array( [Id] => #   [Name] => 7 ...)
    [3] => Array 
        (
            [Id] => #10
            [Name] => gameer123
...`

Comment: It depens on format and if # is part of string. From example it is not clear, so he must edit strictly for his string format.

Comment: And if you can edit a string you should be carefully witch format data have. Because if Name have spaces or other chars like (' " /) etc., it could make a problems.

Comment: Where does everyone get the `$mysql_result_rows` from? This approach can play havoc with spaces. I don't think OP can tidy up the string since it comes from a game server, so RegEx would be a safer option -- although if you can `explode` without ambiguity, explode is more economical.

Answer (score 1):

I made a few assumptions with your data, and there may be a more simplified regex to accomplish this task, but here is a start in any case.

The following code:

```
$pattern = '/#\s*(\d+)\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)"\s+(\d+)\s+(STEAM_\d+:\d+:\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+:\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+:\d+)/';
$subject = '# 7 "player1" 1156 STEAM_0:4:00100365   0 09:52   84    3 175.77.234.241:27505
# 8 "player2" 1149 STEAM_0:0:39163243  2 14:05   52    0 109.175.131.239:65423
# 9 "player " 1159 STEAM_0:0:162  31 07:19   45    0 78.1.126.130:27025
#10 "gameer123" 1146 STEAM_0:0:701135   4 16:41   94    0 191.200.0.100:14097';

$lines = explode("\n",$subject);

$allMatches = array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    preg_match($pattern,$line,$matches); // Extract array of fields
    $allMatches[] = array(
        "Id"       => $matches[1],
        "Name"     => $matches[2],
        "Frags"    => $matches[5],
        "Time"     => $matches[6],
        "Uniqueid" => $matches[4]
    );
}

var_export($allMatches);
```

Got me this result:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Id' => '7',
    'Name' => 'player1',
    'Frags' => '0',
    'Time' => '09:52',
    'Uniqueid' => 'STEAM_0:4:00100365',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Id' => '8',
    'Name' => 'player2',
    'Frags' => '2',
    'Time' => '14:05',
    'Uniqueid' => 'STEAM_0:0:39163243',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Id' => '9',
    'Name' => 'player ',
    'Frags' => '31',
    'Time' => '07:19',
    'Uniqueid' => 'STEAM_0:0:162',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'Id' => '10',
    'Name' => 'gameer123',
    'Frags' => '4',
    'Time' => '16:41',
    'Uniqueid' => 'STEAM_0:0:701135',
  ),
)
```

As Markus-ao has pointed out, the regex pattern I show here is designed to parse out every element from the strings.  To directly solve the problem, the following pattern would be more appropriate:

```
$pattern = '/#\s*(\d+)\s+"([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)"\s+(?:\d+)\s+(STEAM_\d+:\d+:\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+:\d+)/';
```

Note that this change would also change a match array definition to:

```
$allMatches[] = array(
    "Id"       => $matches[1],
    "Name"     => $matches[2],
    "Frags"    => $matches[4],
    "Time"     => $matches[5],
    "Uniqueid" => $matches[3]
);
```

Comment: Why not make the 3rd pattern non-capturing since we don't need it; `\s(?:\d+)\s` or simply `\s+\d+\s+`? Also it's cool that you iterated all the patterns for future reference, but you don't really need to match the stuff after the time. :)

Comment: I guess my intent was, as you said to have all the patterns available if needed, but as you point out the OP already said he only needed a few fields. I may update my answer the next time I'm at a computer. I don't relish the thought of fighting my phone's auto complete on this one.

Comment: Haha just leave them in and make a note on where to snip it, may not be obvious for people who look at regex as `what kind of sorcery is this`. It's cool that you have everything matched.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap same here :)

I've used the [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) website to fine-tune a pattern as accurate as possible to pickup your required segments.

The rest is basically a mechanism to go through them and assemble and print the result.

```php
<?php   
$sampleGmeServerResponse = [
    '# 7 "player1" 1156 STEAM_0:4:00100365   0 09:52   84    3 175.77.234.241:27505',
    '# 8 "player2" 1149 STEAM_0:0:39163243  2 14:05   52    0 109.175.131.239:65423',
    '# 9 "player " 1159 STEAM_0:0:162  31 07:19   45    0 78.1.126.130:27025',
    '#10 "gameer123" 1146 STEAM_0:0:701135   4 16:41   94    0 191.200.0.100:14097',
];

$keys = ['id', 'name', 'userid', 'uniqueid', 'frag', 'time', 'ping', 'loss', 'adr'];
// The regex made here :  https://regex101.com/r/fL9pD7/4 :p
$pattern = '/\s?+(\d+)\s+\"([\w\s]+)\"\s(\d+)\s([\w:"]+)\s+(\d+)\s(\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s([\d.:]+)/';
$result = [];


foreach ($sampleGmeServerResponse as $lineOfData) {
    $matches = [];
    preg_match($pattern, $lineOfData, $matches);
    array_shift($matches);

    $result[] = array_combine($keys, $matches);
}

print_r($result);
```

which results to the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => player1
            [userid] => 1156
            [uniqueid] => STEAM_0:4:00100365
            [frag] => 0
            [time] => 09:52
            [ping] => 84
            [loss] => 3
            [adr] => 175.77.234.241:27505
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => player2
            [userid] => 1149
            [uniqueid] => STEAM_0:0:39163243
            [frag] => 2
            [time] => 14:05
            [ping] => 52
            [loss] => 0
            [adr] => 109.175.131.239:65423
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => player 
            [userid] => 1159
            [uniqueid] => STEAM_0:0:162
            [frag] => 31
            [time] => 07:19
            [ping] => 45
            [loss] => 0
            [adr] => 78.1.126.130:27025
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [name] => gameer123
            [userid] => 1146
            [uniqueid] => STEAM_0:0:701135
            [frag] => 4
            [time] => 16:41
            [ping] => 94
            [loss] => 0
            [adr] => 191.200.0.100:14097
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you have to remove unwanted data from $arr first.

```
$game_array = array();
$key = array("id", "name", "frags", "time",  "uniqueid");

$str = '7 "player1" 1156    STEAM_0:4:00100365   0 09:52   84    3  175.77.234.241:27505';
$arr = explode(" ", $str);

$arr = array_filter($arr);
$first = array_combine($key, $arr);
$game_array[0] = $first;
```