# Getting data with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have the string:

> 14:34:35 - Name:( NAME ) Level( 97 ) Item( ITEM_NAME ) Code( 50401280 ) Unique Number( 842332 13121779 ) Spec Code( 0 ) New( 1 )

I would like to capture some data from this string using `preg_match` function but do not understand much of expressions

How to get?

- NAME
- ITEM_NAME

Comment: What did you tried? I will reccomend you the http://www.phpliveregex.com/ site, where you can test all regex in real time

Comment: Just play with it -> name will be `Name:\( (.*?) \)`

Comment: I was able to preg_match("/(.*) - Name:\( (.*?) \) Level\( (.*?) \) Item\( (.*?) \)/", $input_line, $output_array);

Why use preg_mecth_all @chris85 ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31092573/4960774). similar question and it solution

Comment: and that worked? escape the outer parenthesis `(` and `)` since without `\` they are parsed as output group. Now you only need to get the proper values from the array based on catpuring group `( )` indexes

Comment: I wrote up my explanation, if you have questions please post them. I also presumed this is standardized data and the first three fields will always be present.

Comment: look into http://www.regex101.com it's very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `preg_match_all`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php, not `preg_match`. This way you can loop through all parenthesized values in your targeted string.

```
<?php
$string = '14:34:35 - Name:( NAME ) Level( 97 ) Item( ITEM_NAME ) Code( 50401280 ) Unique Number( 842332 13121779 ) Spec Code( 0 ) New( 1 )
        14:34:35 - Name:( NAME ) Level( 97 ) Item( ITEM_NAME ) Code( 50401280 ) Unique Number( 842332 13121779 ) Spec Code( 0 ) New( 1 )';
preg_match_all('~([a-z: ]+)\(\s*(.*?)\s*\)~i', $string, $values);
foreach($values[1] as $key => $data) {
    if(trim($data) == 'Name:' || trim($data) == 'Item') {
        echo $values[2][$key] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output

> NAME
>   ITEM_NAME
>   NAME
>   ITEM_NAME

If you want whitespaces in the beginning or ending values take out the `\s*`.

You can use the PHP `trim` function to remove the leading/trailing whitespaces on instances where you want it removed.

```
<?php
$string = '14:34:35 - Name:( NAME ) Level( 97 ) Item( ITEM_NAME ) Code( 50401280 ) Unique Number( 842332 13121779 ) Spec Code( 0 ) New( 1 )
        14:34:35 - Name:( NAME ) Level( 97 ) Item( ITEM_NAME ) Code( 50401280 ) Unique Number( 842332 13121779 ) Spec Code( 0 ) New( 1 )';
preg_match_all('~([a-z: ]+)\((.*?)\)~i', $string, $values);
foreach($values[1] as $key => $data) {
    if(trim($data) == 'Name:' || trim($data) == 'Item') {
        echo $values[2][$key] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xG9tI3/2

Further reading on regexs:
http://www.rexegg.com/
http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: Niiiceee @chris85 !
Thank you =D